# How to write a Xpath Expression comparing two attributes or nodes

Tags: xpath, attributes, xmlnode

Given the following sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Patients>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="996-756-495" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
    <id extension="775-756-495" root="2.16.840.1.113883.14.6"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>Henry</given>
        <family>Levin</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19320924"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
      <name>Good Health Clinic</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="2012030111:32"/>
  </patientRole>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="65" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.933"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>Paul</given>
        <family>Pappel</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19551217"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id extension="84756-11241-283-OPTD-3322" root="1.2.3.4.5.6.1.8.9.0"/>
      <name> Dr.med. Hans Topp-Glucklich</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="201201152200"/>
  </patientRole>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="800001" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>JEANNE</given>
        <family>PETIT</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19480105"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
      <name>Good Health Clinic</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="20120101T22:00"/>
  </patientRole>
</Patients>
```

How would I write a X-Path expression for the following:

Family names for the male patients (gender code="M")

Any help is greatly appreciated I am new to XML/Xpath and i have tried multiple ways and its not generating what i need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

`/Patients/patientRole/patient[administrativeGenderCode/@code='M']/name/family`

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel. Now just a quick question that's a predicate right. The / after the administrativeGenderCode basically tells it to look at the next section for the code? Then I just /path into the rest of the section im comparing it to or rather need to relate it to?

Comment: @user2228233 - Yes that's a predicate. The `administrativeGenderCode/@code` is the `code` attribute in the `administrativeGenderCode` element. Take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-path-expressions

Comment: Same examples im stuck on how to do this: 
Number of patients admitted to "Good Health Clinic" in January 2012:

The closest i was able to get was:
/Patients/patientRole[providerOrganization/name="Good Health Clinic"]/admissionTime

but its returning both admission values not sure how to specify jan 2012

Comment: @user2228233 - If the date formats are consistent, you could try `/Patients/patientRole[providerOrganization/name='Good Health Clinic' and substring(admissionTime/@value,1,6)='201201']`

Comment: strange with that one it works in my viewer but when i submit it to the site i get "Incorrect! XPath expression returns node list."